# The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 : Data type 0x72 is unknown

Tags: c#, android, ios, json, wcf

I am using WCF services to get and post data to server from mobile app (IOS and Android).

After service call I am getting response as

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 : Data type 0x72 is unknown.

In local machine it is working properly. As checked the exception log it is related to ".Net SqlClient Data Provider".

I am using JSON object to send request to services. Below code is used to get list of workarea based on user.

Json request :

```
{"request":{"UserName":"abc@gmail.com","Password":"1234"}}
```

Service code to fetch data :

```
public class WorkareaResponse
{
    public List<Workarea> WorkareaItems { get; set; }
}

public class Workarea
{
    public string WorkareaId { get; set; }
    public string WorkareaName { get; set; }
    public string CityId { get; set; }
}

public WorkareaResponse RestoreWorkarea(ServiceRequest request)
{
    WorkareaResponse response = new WorkareaResponse();
    List<Workarea> Items = new List<Workarea>();

    ds = presenter.RestoreWorkarea(request);

    Items = (from p in ds.Tables[0].Select().ToList()
         select new Workarea
         {
             WorkareaId = Convert.ToString(p.ItemArray.GetValue(0)),
             WorkareaName = Convert.ToString(p.ItemArray.GetValue(1)),
             CityId = Convert.ToString(p.ItemArray.GetValue(2))
         }).ToList();

    response.WorkareaItems = Items;
}
```